# pd conditional cumsum and percentage

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I have a dataframe of the following shape:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["trial"] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
df["correct"] = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
df["responding_subject"] = ["one", "two", "two", "two", "one", "two", "one", "one", "one", "two"]
```

I want to add 2 new columns that represent the accuracy (i.e. proportion correct) of one's own trials up to this point.

E.g. df["acc_one"] at index 4 would compute the **accuracy of all previous** (trials 0-3) **own** (but not partner!) **trials**.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can compute the expanding accuracy using `groupby`:

```
g = df.groupby('responding_subject')['correct']
df['accuracy'] = g.cumsum()/(g.cumcount()+1)
```

output:

```
   trial  correct responding_subject  accuracy
0      0        1                one  1.000000
1      1        0                two  0.000000
2      2        1                two  0.500000
3      3        1                two  0.666667
4      4        0                one  0.500000
5      5        0                two  0.500000
6      6        0                one  0.333333
7      7        1                one  0.500000
8      8        0                one  0.400000
9      9        1                two  0.600000
```

There is no real need to split accuracies in different columns, however if you really want to, add a `pivot` step:

```
df.join(df.pivot(columns='responding_subject', values='accuracy').add_prefix('acc_'))
```

output:

```
   trial  correct responding_subject  accuracy   acc_one   acc_two
0      0        1                one  1.000000  1.000000       NaN
1      1        0                two  0.000000       NaN  0.000000
2      2        1                two  0.500000       NaN  0.500000
3      3        1                two  0.666667       NaN  0.666667
4      4        0                one  0.500000  0.500000       NaN
5      5        0                two  0.500000       NaN  0.500000
6      6        0                one  0.333333  0.333333       NaN
7      7        1                one  0.500000  0.500000       NaN
8      8        0                one  0.400000  0.400000       NaN
9      9        1                two  0.600000       NaN  0.600000
```

Comment: thank you! Having two columns make further analysis way easier for me. How can I have, instead of the NaN, just the previous cumulative accuracy? E.g. index 5, I would just want 0.5 for acc_one as well, because it is the cumulative accuracy so far.

Comment: use `ffill` to fill NaNs with the previous value